# configuring a Fibre Channel switch

Tags: configuration, dell, fibre-channel

*(I'm asking this for a friend and I'm don't know most of this technical stuff, so I'm sorry in advance if I'm not clear enough to describe the problem)*

> Where can i find any information about
>   how to **configure** a Fibre Channel
>   switch ( QLocic , Mini GBic, QME2572 )
>   to make it communicate with a Dell
>   R905 and a Dell M905 Blade Server ?

Many thanks in advance

Pierre

Comment: ummm... RTM? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Plug the server into the switch with the appropriate cable.

For more complicated settings, refer to the switch's manual (which should have come with the switch or be available for download from the manufacturer).

However from the question, I don't think this is what you want.  It sounds like you have two computers and one FC switch.  Unless you also have a storage device, you need to configure one side to pretend to be the storage. Note that in any case you'll need Fiber Channel cards to make this work.